# Android custom Animation for an ArcShape

Tags: java, android, animation

First let me explain my goal. I am trying to make an `Animation` that changes the properties of an `ArcShape`. An `ArcShape's` constructor takes two fields: `startAngle` and `sweepAngle`. I want to animate the `sweepAngle` so that it appears on screen as a continuously shrinking circle.

You can picture this animation by imagining PacMan. Imagine his mouth is closed. This animation would be akin to him opening his upper jaw more and more until there was no more PacMan.

Now... I have a couple of issues with implementing this. First, once an `ArcShape` is created, there are no built in methods of changing it's `sweepAngle`. This brings me to my first question: Is there any way to override `ArcShape` and implement some `setSweepAngle` method? Or will I have to create a `new ArcShape` for each `sweepAngle` I wish to display?

Now on to the second issue... Assuming I found a solution to the first issue, how could I create this `Animation`? This is the gist of what I have now:

```
public class OpenPacman extends Animation {
  public OpenPacman(float startAngle, float sweepAngle) {
    mStartAngle = startAngle;
    mSweepAngle = sweepAngle;
  }

  @Override
  protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    /* This represents the current sweepAngle */
    float currAngle = mStartAngle + ((mSweepAngle - mStartAngle) * interpolatedTime);

    //Now I need to update the ArcShape's sweepAngle to currAngle. But HOW?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found a solution. I have a class that extends `View` We'll call this `Pacman` I nested my custom `Animation` within this `Pacman` class. This allowed me to access the `member variables` of the `Pacman` class.

```
public class Pacman extends View {
  float mSweepAngle;
  ...
  //include constructors
  //override onMeasure
  ...

  /* Here we override onDraw */
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    RectF oval = new RectF(canvas.getClipBounds());
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0, mCurrAngle, true, p);
  }

  /* Here we define our nested custom animation */
  public class OpenPacman extends Animation {
    float mStartAngle;
    float mSweepAngle;

    public OpenPacman (int startAngle, int sweepAngle, long duration) {
      mStartAngle = startAngle;
      mSweepAngle = sweepAngle;
      setDuration(duration);
      setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
      float currAngle = mStartAngle + ((mSweepAngle - mStartAngle) * interpolatedTime);
      Pacman.this.mCurrAngle = -currAngle; //negative for counterclockwise animation.
    }
  }
}
```

Now when the custom animation updates the container classes `mCurrAngle`, `onDraw` is automatically called, which draws the appropriate `ArcShape`.

Comment: I had to add "invalidate();" to the applyTransformation method so the view will reDraw with the new angle.

Comment: I followed the instructions but my custom view does not appear on the UI. can you post your full code ?

Comment: I know, forever old post.... But I don't see how this animates the arc. It just updates the current angle and then you can redraw it but it is not animated. So... How did you animate this exactly?

Comment: Don't use this outdated "solution". It doesn't work. Even if you waste time and draw a line, it won't animate. See https://medium.com/@dbottillo/animate-android-custom-view-a94473412054.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better off extending Drawable and override the draw() function to modify the sweep angle on each call and draw the corresponding arc. Draw is typically called every time the object is updated, which will mean that you'll have to make a new ArcShape every time it's drawn
Animation is more for performing transformations on Views and other UI components.

Something like:

```
public class OpenPacman  
{

public OpenPacman(float startAngle, float sweepAngle) {  
    this.mStartAngle = startAngle;  
    this.mSweepAngle = sweepAngle;  
    this.wakaWaka = new ArcShape(this.startAngle, this.mSweepAngle);  
} 

public void draw(Canvas c){  
  //Do drawing stuff here with the canvas
}

//Your other functions for calculating angle, etc and making the ArcShape changes
//Can call these from inside draw function so that when the view that contains your
//object calls draw, it updates correctly.

public float mStartAngle;  
public float msweepAngle;  
private ArcShape wakaWaka;  
}
```

Hope this gets you on the right track.