# Android Animate drawing of arc

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I have a arc which is being drawn in a canvas ontop of a circle to provide a pecentage chart, Much like the CyanogenMod Circular Battery. How would I go about adding a animation to animate smoothly the arc being drawn from the starting angle to the angle.

Comment: I think answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566118/android-custom-animation-for-an-arcshape